# Feedback json format wrong

Tags: ios, json, swift

This is my feedback json string:

```
{"name":"abc", "cardNumber":"1234567890", "data": [{A data},{B data}...]}
```

I use this function to send data, then get json and encode:

```
func uploadData(word:String){
    var request = URLRequest(url: url!, cachePolicy: .reloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData, timeoutInterval: 30)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    request.httpBody = word.data(using: .utf8)
    request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    let session = URLSession(configuration: URLSessionConfiguration.default)
    session.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) in
        if let data = data{
            do{
            let data = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers)
                print(data) //I want to know what is this so I print
            }catch{
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
    }).resume()
}
```

But the console always says:`The data couldn't be read because it isn't in the correct format`

This json can be format and read in android if I use `JSONObject.getJSONArray("myValue")...`
I try to use `print(data)`(without json encode) to show if there is any data in feedback and I get 400byte in console, so I'm sure there is data send back to me. 
**UPDATE 12/28:**

```
{"name":"abc",
 "cardNumber":"1234567890",
 "data": [{day:20171228, time: 09:10:11},
          {day:20171226, time: 20:00:12},
          {day:20171227, time: 15:30:22}
         ]
}
```

I'm sure this json can be read in android, the receiver and sender I use is vb.net, it use `sendingString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(JSONClass)` to become json string, then convert to byte to send out.

**UPDATE 12/28 new**
After trying so much, I found string can get the feedback, but the value of `name` is Chinese word, other value is English and number, only `name` is unreadable, now I'm checking which `String.Encoding` will work, then if I encode it success, I will try to format to json Array.

Comment: Can you print full JSON?

Comment: Are you sure that your web-service is returning correct JSON format ? I mean whether you are getting success result or it's returning any other data (Error strings ?)

Comment: @MidhunMP  I try to use String to get the feedback will return nil, and there is a funny thing I still have no way to find out why this happen: if I use `seesion.uploadTask` and `session.downloadTask` , I can get feedback and read, but the result is `{"name":, "cardNumber":, "data":} ` , there is no value  in json, until this, I still can't figure it out why download will send a unknown data to reqeust the download...

Comment: @SucharuHasija I updated my full json string, thanks~

Comment: It's because your JSON is actually invalid. The `day` and `time` keys should have been enquoted, like this `{"day": "20171228", "time": "09:10:11"}` Different JSON parsers impose different validity checks on the data. If you can't change the server, your best bet is to find a JSON library that can accept this invalid data

Comment: @CodeDifferent I got string back if I use `String.Encoding.init(rawValue:5)`, but if I first use string to get feedback then can I format it to json?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this one?

```
func uploadData(word:String){
var request = URLRequest(url: url!, cachePolicy: .reloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData, timeoutInterval: 30)
request.httpMethod = "POST"
request.httpBody = word.data(using: .utf8)
request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
let session = URLSession(configuration: URLSessionConfiguration.default)
session.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) in
    if let data = data{
          if let returnData = String(data: data!, encoding: .utf8) {
          print(returnData)
          } else {
          print("Invalid Data Coming")
         }

        do{
        let data = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as?  [String: AnyObject]
            print(data) //I want to know what is this so I print
        }catch{
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
}).resume()
```

}

Comment: Change option to []? the console still says `The data couldn't be read because it isn't in the correct format.`

Comment: I have updated the code and tried to get String information from your data. Can you tell me what is showing in the print value?

Comment: Can you tell the exact URL and JSON you are sending? I will update answer according to that. 

Hope that make sense

Comment: The String gets `Invalid Data Coming`, and the json gets `The data couldn't be read because it isn't in the correctt format`.
I think one of the reason cause the incorrect format is the value of `name` is Chinese word, in android I use BIG5 to read feedback then I can and get the value.

Comment: There is nothing like that in JSON Formatting.  Why not, you use almanofire for the same task

Comment: I got the string back! but the name is unreadable, I'm keep trying another encode.
So I'm sure it really send feedback to me.